# Used display:none for media queries and scroll is wrong fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I used display:none for one of sections so its visible only on devices with less than 576px. And anchors are wrong, and scrolling jumps from second to first section. How to fix it?

This is the 
[page](http://jakubkusmider.pl)

Comment: Related with https://stackoverflow.com/a/36643702/1081396

Answer (score 1):

According to [GitHub's plugin docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2098), this is still an open issue that needs to be fixed by the lib's developer. What he mentioned as a workaround is destroying fullpage.js and reinitializing it again without the faulty section. (Whenever you are going to do that is up to you to find appropriate, whether on screen width resize, page loads, etc etc)

Comment: Exactly. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36643702/1081396) which covers a very similar issue.