# Fullpage.js and turbolinks integration (fullpage not works correctly)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js, turbolinks

Hello I am trying to use [turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/blob/master/dist/turbolinks.js) and [fullpage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/), first of all I create index.html and insert this code to head tag:

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<script>


$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
console.log("It works on each visit!")

 $('#fullpage').fullpage({
  anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage'],
  sectionsColor: ['#191919', '#191919', '#191919'],
  responsiveHeight: 600,
  navigation: true,
            
  
  navigationPosition: 'right', 
  afterResponsive: function(isResponsive){
  }
 });
});
</head>
<body>
....my html code here ..
</body>
```

also I created second page demo_page.html and inserted same head block to html code. On demo_page.html there is a link that going to index.html ([Testing](/index.html) ), when I click to link it loads index.html through turbolinks but without fullpage functions (in console log no errors except for this fullPage: Fullpage.js can only be initialized once and you are doing it multiple times!) and when I refresh index.html (by F5 browser) it loaded normally with working scrolling sections and other functionality of Fullpage.js
How to fix this problem and somebody have a working open sorce project of fullpage.js and turbolinks integration?

Comment: It is all about dynamic content and destroying and initializing fullPage.js. First of all, are you sure you need turbolinks? Check [this topic](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/115).

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you can not initialize fullPage.js multiple times.

Just destroy it and initialize it again every time you load a new page with new content. 
Check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36643702/1081396) for more info.
Also, check [this topic in fullPage.js issues forum](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/115).